# How to disable "Do not allow refresh/replace to modify must not be enabled for views"?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

My database couldn't be deployed, because IBM GNA/Accessibility Filter says:

> Do not allow refresh/replace to modify must not be enabled for views
>   -Std 3.2.2.2.3. Must have exception for all others -Std 3.1.1.1

Where can I disable it?

Comment: What steps did you do to get the above error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncheck the property from the view (via list of views in Designer):

[image]

---

IBM GNA/Accessibility Filter is an internal IBM deployment process for deploying IBM Notes databases to Domino servers within IBM. So including those details in your question is not necessary :-)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to disable this option for following files/design elements: plugin.xml, build.properties, .project? I opened Db in Java Perpective in Designer, but I didn't see this option. ![unknown design elements](https://yadi.sk/i/HlKOCpV2uTFEX)

Comment: You could try those perspectives :
- Domino Designer
- XPages

I'm not sure though about the specific design elements you are refering to. Seems like stuff you would care about in a pure Java project but, afaik, not in a Notes database no matter how much Java you crammed in there.

Well, at any rate, this "Prohibit design refresh or design to modify" is a very ancient Lotus Notes idiosyncrasy that would have little relevance for the things you are talking about, if they exist at all.

Comment: @Vitaly don't worry about those design elements with regards to the internal IBM deployment process